# How do I use SQL LEFT() in Symfony2 query builder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

Here's the line that's making my query fail.

```
$query = $query->where('a.field LIKE :keyword OR LEFT(a.otherfield, 3) = LEFT(:keyword, 3)');
```

I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 104: Error: Expected known function, got 'LEFT'
```

This SQL code works:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE field LIKE 'searchterm'
OR LEFT(`otherfield`, 3) = LEFT('searchterm', 3)
```

Why does LEFT() return an error? Is there a different way to do it with query builder?

Comment: You will have to implement your own DQL function, please see [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/29/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine LEFT mysql function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761748/doctrine-left-mysql-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761748/doctrine-left-mysql-function). Otherwise, try the old school way! [native-sql-with-doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

@Houssem Zitoun's answer was good, and I'm marking it as the answer because it's relevant to my question. It's not the answer I used however

I already had the query written in sql that I wanted to use, so i decided to use a custom query with doctrine. It explains here how to do it. [Symfony2 & Doctrine: Create custom SQL-Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862389/symfony2-doctrine-create-custom-sql-query/12862523#12862523)